# TypeError: _this2.somefunction not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the status (parent/teacher/child) of the user I want to log in using the function **checkStatusLogin**, to redirect the user to the corresponding page

The problem is that I'm getting this error my console : *Error getting document: [TypeError: _this2.checkStatusLogin is not a function. (In '_this2.checkStatusLogin(status)', '_this2.checkStatusLogin' is undefined)]*

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground,Image,ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import background from "../Images/background.jpg";
import independoLogo from "../Images/Independo.png";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
require('firebase/auth')
require('firebase/firestore')


const {width : WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window')

const screenHeight=Dimensions.get('window').height
const screenWidth=Dimensions.get('window').width


class LoginAdult extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      email:'',
      password:'',
      isLoading:false,
    }
    this.checkStatusLogin=this.checkStatusLogin.bind(this);
  }

  checkStatusLogin(status)
  {
    alert("The user logged in");
    console.log("checkStatus = ",status);
    if(status==="Parent")
    {
      console.log("checkStatusParent = ",status);
      this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeParent");
    }
    if(status==="Teacher")
    {
      console.log("checkStatusTeacher = ",status);
      this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeTeacher");
    }
    if(status==="Child")
    {
      console.log("checkStatusTeacher = ",status);
      this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeChild");
    }
  }


  LoginPress= async()=>{
    const {email,password,}=this.state;
    global.stat;
    if(this.state.email && this.state.password)
    {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
    {
      if (user != null) 
      {
        var docRef=firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user.uid);
        docRef.get().then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              const {status} = doc.data();
              console.log("Status = ",status);
              this.checkStatusLogin(status);
          } else {
              console.log("No such document!");
          }
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
    }
  }))

    
    .catch((error)=>{
      switch(error.code)
      {
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
          alert("Please, enter a valid mail")
          break;
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
          alert('A user with this email doesnt exist, please sign Up')
          break;
      }
    
      
    }
    )
  }
  else{
    alert("Please enter email and password!")
  }

  }



  render(){
  return (
    <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.imagebackground}>
      <View style={{header:25,backgroundColor:"",alignItems:'center',marginTop:40}}>
      <Image source={independoLogo} style={styles.logo}/>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1,borderWidth:0,borderColor:'transparent',margin:40,marginTop:0,marginBottom:220}}>
      {this.state.isLoading?
        <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',zIndex:1000,elevation:1000}}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black"/>
        </View>
      :null}
        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"#F9f3fc",alignItems:'center',paddingTop:35,borderRadius:15,borderStyle:'dotted solid double'}}>



            <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:30,paddingBottom:30}}>LOGIN</Text>

            <TextInput 
              style={styles.input} 
              placeholderTextColor={'black'} 
              placeholder={'Email'}
              onChangeText={inputEmail=>this.setState({email:inputEmail})}/>

            <TextInput 
              style={styles.input} 
              placeholderTextColor={'black'} 
              placeholder={'Password'} 
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onChangeText={inputPassword=>this.setState({password:inputPassword})}/>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin} onPress={()=>this.LoginPress()}>
              <Text style={{fontWeight:'600'}}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>


          <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("SignUp")}>
                            <Text>Dont have an account?  </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row',margin:4}}
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("ForgotPasswordAdult")}>
                            <Text style={{textDecorationLine:'underline' ,fontSize:16 ,fontWeight:'bold',}}>
                              Forgot Password?  
                              </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
}

export default LoginAdult;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following line from your our code

```
this.checkStatusLogin = this.checkStatusLogin.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the bind function and use an arrow function :

```
  checkStatusLogin= (status) { ... }
```